# possible for all outbound smtp to run through proxy?

Tags: centos, smtp, proxy, haproxy

Is it possible to setup my centos 6.5 so all outgoing port 25 is run through a proxy. I have incoming smtp/port 25 coming to my mail server through HAproxy but i would like the outgoing to do the same so the receiving mail server sees the connection coming from my load balancer IP.
i have been searching the net for last hour but can't find any examples or setups.

Answer (score 0):

While it might be possible,  make sure your mail server identifies itself using the name assigned to your haproxy server.

By design SMTP is resilient to network and server failures.  I can't see a good use case for putting an email server behind haproxy.   It might make sense to put and IMAP or POP server behind haproxy.

If you have a single email server, then you can do what you wish much simpler with `iptables` rules.  If you have multiple email servers, each should have a unique IP address.  These addresses should have DNS entries that pass rDNS for the domain name they identify themselves as.  The mail servers can (usually)  use a domain name different from that of the host they run on.